# mscorlib produces weird assembly references on some machines

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have run into a weird problem which I am unable to find the root cause. As I understand mscorlib does not reference other assemblies. However, when I run below code

`Type t = typeof(System.AssemblyLoadEventArgs);`

`AssemblyName[] references = t.Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();`

It produces two references. So mscorlib 4.0.0.0 is referencing mscorlib 2.0.0.0 and powerleech.dll. I don't even know what powerleech.dll is and where it comes from.

This output is on some machines only, on others I get 0 references as I expect. All machines are windows 7. Above is sample code which illustrates the problem faced by a bigger application, I have omitted other details. Any idea what could be causing above behavior.

Comment: A quick search suggests that the "powerleech" dll is part of an anti-virus suite's option for PowerShell and is likely injected at runtime through no doubt dubious means (sufficiently advanced AV is often indistinguishable from malware). This in turn may also explain the reference to mscorlib v2, if that DLL is targeted to the v2 runtime.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. It did turn out to be the antivirus. The machines showing strange behavior with above code had a new update of the antivirus. After uninstalling that version, the problem seems to have gone away.